# Prepending dash on a Ruby string doesn't freeze the string object?

Tags: ruby, string, objectid

According to Ruby talk's mailing list about [string memory optimization](https://rubytalk.org/t/psa-string-memory-use-reduction-techniques/74477), prepending a string with a dash (`-`) should freeze a string:

```
-"fdsa".object_id
```

Which prints

```
70226306210540
```

However:

```
-"fdsa".object_id
-"fdsa".object_id # an attempt to freeze the same object again
```

Prints

```
-70226306210540
-70226306227620
```

Which implies the string is not frozen because a new object is created.

The `-"<string>"` is supposed to be an update after version 2.2 to replace `"fdsa".freeze` but doesn't seem to work...

However, the old style works:

```
"asdf".freeze.object_id
"asdf".freeze.object_id
```

Prints

```
70226188545780
70226188545780
```

What did I miss?

Comment: _"Which implies the string is not frozen"_ – just because you have two instances doesn't mean they aren't frozen. Freezing and de-duplication are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because of the procedure order.

```
(-"fdsa").object_id
(-"fdsa").object_id
```

should be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding about what *freezing* an object does. From [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-2D-40) (emphasis mine)

> `-string → frozen_string`
>
> Returns a frozen, **possibly pre-existing** copy of the string.
>
> The returned String will be deduplicated as long as it does not have any instance variables set on it.

There's no guarantee that the resulting string object will be the same as all other strings like it. That's an optimization the interpreter is *allowed* to make, but not required to.

If you require the same object, then you're not looking for strings: you're looking for [symbols](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Symbol.html). We can get a symbol with the `:literal` symbol syntax, or using `String#intern` to convert a string into one. This is guaranteed to return the same symbol each time.

```
irb(main):013:0> "fdsa".intern
=> :fdsa
irb(main):014:0> "fdsa".intern.object_id
=> 340
irb(main):015:0> "fdsa".intern.object_id
=> 340
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *operator precedence*. The message sending binary infix operator has higher precedence than the unary prefix minus operator. Therefore, your code is equivalent to

```ruby
-("fdsa".object_id)

# which is equivalent to

"fdsa".object_id().-@()
```

not to

```ruby
(-"fdsa").object_id

# which is equivalent to

"fdsa".-@().object_id()
```

as you seem to think.

In other words, you are not asking for the object ID of a de-duplicated frozen string, but for the negative of the object IDs of two mutable strings.

You can easily verify the precedence yourself:

```ruby
class Foo
  def -@
    p __callee__; self
  end

  def some_method
    p __callee__; self
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

-foo.some_method
# :some_method
# :-@

-(foo.some_method)
# :some_method
# :-@

(-foo).some_method
# :-@
# :some_method
```

If you try something like this:

```ruby
(-"fdsa").object_id
(-"fdsa").object_id
```

You should see the same object ID twice.